# I want to know how to debug this code because it gives me error

Tags: python

The following is a code for the cvrp problem using simmulated annealing algorithm but im trying to incorporate the time windows as delivery schedule. but its not working

```
# Read all sheets from the Excel file into a dictionary of DataFrames
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Model Information for time windows 23rd March.xlsx')
sheets_dict = {sheet_name: xls.parse(sheet_name) for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names}

# Extract data from each sheet
customer_data_df = sheets_dict['Customer Data']
delivery_schedule_df = sheets_dict['Delivery Schedule']
vehicle_df = sheets_dict['Vehicle']
distance_matrix_df = sheets_dict['Distance Matrix']

# Set index for Customer Data and Vehicle Data
customer_data_df.set_index('Customer Name', inplace=True)
vehicle_df.set_index('Vehicle Number', inplace=True)

# Extract necessary data
demands = customer_data_df['Avg Sale'].values
time_windows = {}
visit_frequency = delivery_schedule_df['Visit Frequency']

for customer in customer_data_df.index:
    time_windows[customer] = []
    early_time, late_time = None, None
    visit_frequency_count = 0
    for day in delivery_schedule_df.columns[:-1]:
        if customer in delivery_schedule_df.index:
            if delivery_schedule_df.loc[customer, day] == 1:
                visit_frequency_count += 1
                if day == 'Monday':
                    early_time, late_time = 0, 24 * 60
                elif day == 'Tuesday':
                    early_time, late_time = 24 * 60, 2 * 24 * 60
                elif day == 'Wednesday':
                    early_time, late_time = 2 * 24 * 60, 3 * 24 * 60
                elif day == 'Thursday':
                    early_time, late_time = 3 * 24 * 60, 4 * 24 * 60
                elif day == 'Friday':
                    early_time, late_time = 4 * 24 * 60, 5 * 24 * 60
                elif day == 'Saturday':
                    early_time, late_time = 5 * 24 * 60, 6 * 24 * 60
                time_windows[customer].append((early_time, late_time))
                if visit_frequency_count == visit_frequency[customer]:
                    break  # Break the loop once all visit frequencies are assigned
        else:
            print(f"Warning: Customer '{customer}' not found in delivery schedule dataframe.")

# Add a time window for the 'DC' customer
time_windows['DC'] = [(0, 24 * 60)]

# Adjust time windows to include DC, assuming DC operates across the entire period
dc_time_window = [(0, 24 * 60 * 7)]  # Example: Full week operation
time_windows['DC'] = dc_time_window

vehicle_capacities = vehicle_df['Load Capacity'].values
distance_matrix = distance_matrix_df.values

# Create a dictionary to map customer names to their indices
# Add DC with index 0 and adjust customer indices accordingly
customer_indices = {'DC': 0}
customer_indices.update({customer: i + 1 for i, customer in enumerate(customer_data_df.index)})

# Ensure demands includes DC with a demand of 0 at the start
demands = np.insert(customer_data_df['Avg Sale'].values, 0, 0)

def preto_rule(distance_matrix, demands, vehicle_capacities, time_windows, customer_indices):
    print("\nGenerating initial solution using Preto's rule:")
    vehicle_routes = [[] for _ in range(len(vehicle_capacities))]
    remaining_capacities = vehicle_capacities.copy()

    # Initialize routes starting with DC
    vehicle_routes = [['DC'] for _ in range(len(vehicle_capacities))]
    remaining_capacities = vehicle_capacities.copy()

    # Sort customers based on their time window start times
    customers = []
    for customer in time_windows:
        if time_windows[customer] is not None:
            for time_window in time_windows[customer]:
                if time_window[0] is not None:
                    customers.append((customer, time_window[0]))

    customers = sorted(customers, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)

    assigned_customers = 0

    for i, (customer, _) in enumerate(customers):
        print(f"\nProcessing customer {i+1}/{len(customers)}: {customer}")
        assigned = False
        smallest_increase = float('inf')
        best_route = None

        for vehicle_id, vehicle in enumerate(vehicle_routes):
            if demands[customer_indices[customer]] <= remaining_capacities[vehicle_id]:
                route_with_customer = vehicle[:]
                route_with_customer.append(customer)
                new_route_distance = calculate_total_distance(route_with_customer, distance_matrix, customer_indices)
                new_route_time = calculate_total_time(route_with_customer, time_windows)
                increase = new_route_distance + new_route_time - (calculate_total_distance(vehicle, distance_matrix, customer_indices) + calculate_total_time(vehicle, time_windows))

                if increase < smallest_increase:
                    smallest_increase = increase
                    best_route = vehicle_id

        if best_route is not None:
            vehicle_routes[best_route].append(customer)
            remaining_capacities[best_route] -= demands[customer_indices[customer]]
            assigned_customers += 1
            print(f"Assigned customer {customer} to vehicle {best_route + 1}, new capacity: {remaining_capacities[best_route]}")
        else:
            print(f"Warning: Customer {customer} could not be assigned to a vehicle.")

    print(f"\nInitial solution generated successfully: {assigned_customers} out of {len(customers)} customers assigned to a vehicle.")
    print("Vehicle routes:", vehicle_routes)
    print("Remaining capacities:", remaining_capacities)

    return vehicle_routes, remaining_capacities


def calculate_total_distance(route, distance_matrix, customer_indices):
    route_distance = 0
    for i in range(1, len(route)):
        route_distance += distance_matrix[customer_indices[route[i-1]]][customer_indices[route[i-1]]]
    return route_distance

def calculate_total_time(route, time_windows):
    total_time = 0
    for i in range(len(route) - 1):
        current_customer = route[i]
        next_customer = route[i + 1]

        if current_customer == 'DC':
            total_time += time_windows[next_customer][0][0]
        elif next_customer == 'DC':
            total_time += time_windows[current_customer][-1][1] - time_windows[current_customer][-1][0]
        else:
            total_time += (time_windows[next_customer][0][0] - time_windows[current_customer][-1][0])

    return total_time

def check_capacity_after_move(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, from_route, to_route, customer_index, current_time):
    if not check_time_windows(time_windows, routes[from_route][customer_index], current_time)[0]:
        return False, None

    customer = routes[from_route][customer_index]
    if demands[customer_indices[customer]] > (vehicle_capacities[to_route] - sum(demands[customer_indices[c]] for c in routes[to_route])):
        return False, None
    return True, vehicle_capacities[to_route] - sum(demands[customer_indices[c]] for c in routes[to_route])

def swap_customers_between_routes(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, current_time):
    print("\nSwapping customers between routes:")
    route_a, route_b = random.sample(range(len(routes)), 2)
    if not routes[route_a] or not routes[route_b]:
        return routes

    customer_a, customer_b = random.choice(routes[route_a]), random.choice(routes[route_b])

    if (check_capacity_after_move(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, route_a, route_b, routes[route_a].index(customer_a), current_time)[0] and
        check_capacity_after_move(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, route_b, route_a, routes[route_b].index(customer_b), current_time)[0]):
        routes[route_a][routes[route_a].index(customer_a)], routes[route_b][routes[route_b].index(customer_b)] = customer_b, customer_a
        print(f"Swapped customer {customer_a} from route {route_a + 1} with customer {customer_b} from route {route_b + 1}")

    return routes

def relocate_customer_between_routes(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, current_time):
    print("\nRelocating customer between routes:")
    from_route = random.choice(range(len(routes)))
    if not routes[from_route]:
        return routes

    to_route = random.choice([r for r in range(len(routes)) if r != from_route])
    customer_index = random.choice(range(len(routes[from_route])))

    if check_capacity_after_move(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, from_route, to_route, customer_index, current_time)[0]:
        routes[to_route].append(routes[from_route].pop(customer_index))
        print(f"Relocated customer {routes[to_route][-1]} from route {from_route + 1} to route {to_route + 1}")

    return routes

def get_neighbor(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, current_time):
    if random.choice([True, False]):
        return swap_customers_between_routes(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, current_time)
    else:
        return relocate_customer_between_routes(routes, vehicle_capacities, demands, time_windows, current_time)

def acceptance_probability(old_costs, new_costs, temperature):
    weight_distance = 0.5
    weight_time = 0.5

    old_cost = weight_distance * old_costs[0] + weight_time * old_costs[1]
    new_cost = weight_distance * new_costs[0] + weight_time * new_costs[1]

    if new_cost < old_cost:
        return 1.0
    else:
        return math.exp((old_cost - new_cost) / temperature)

def simulated_annealing(distance_matrix, demands, vehicle_capacities, time_windows, initial_temperature, cooling_rate, customer_indices):
    print("\nStarting simulated annealing:")
    temperature = initial_temperature
    current_solution, remaining_capacities = preto_rule(distance_matrix, demands, vehicle_capacities, time_windows, customer_indices)
    best_solution = current_solution
    best_costs = (calculate_total_distance(best_solution, distance_matrix, customer_indices), calculate_total_time(best_solution, time_windows))

    while temperature > 0.1:
        neighbor_solution = get_neighbor(current_solution, remaining_capacities, demands, time_windows, 0)
        current_costs = (calculate_total_distance(current_solution, distance_matrix, customer_indices), calculate_total_time(current_solution, time_windows))
        neighbor_costs = (calculate_total_distance(neighbor_solution, distance_matrix, customer_indices), calculate_total_time(neighbor_solution, time_windows))

        if acceptance_probability(current_costs, neighbor_costs, temperature) > random.random():
            current_solution = neighbor_solution
            current_costs = neighbor_costs
            print(f"Accepted new solution at temperature {temperature:.2f}: {current_costs}")

        if neighbor_costs < best_costs:
            best_solution = neighbor_solution
            best_costs = neighbor_costs
            print(f"Found new best solution at temperature {temperature:.2f}: {best_costs}")

        temperature *= 1 - cooling_rate

    return best_solution, best_costs

initial_temperature = 1000
cooling_rate = 0.003
best_solution, best_costs = simulated_annealing(distance_matrix, demands, vehicle_capacities, time_windows, initial_temperature, cooling_rate, customer_indices)

print("\nBest Solution:")
for i, route in enumerate(best_solution):
    print(f"Vehicle {i+1}: {route}")

print("\nBest Distance Cost:", best_costs[0])
print("Best Time Cost:", best_costs[1])
```

Comment: Please be more detailed on what the exact issue is so we can better help you, especially given quite a lot of code is shared. What do you mean with 'trying to incorporate the time windows as delivery schedule' and 'its not working'? See also [the page on how to ask a good question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: This is a route optimization problem based on Mult objective capacitated vehicle routing problem with time windows using pareto optimization. We are to get optimal routes where we are making the routes in a way that our customer demands are being satisfied without violating the vehicle capacities. The objective in this is distance minimization along with ensuring that the delivery schedule is met. 

The element of pareto optimization needs to be included to ensure that the pareto optimal front gives us the tradeoffs of different scenarios.

Comment: i get this error 
--> 223 best_solution, best_costs = simulated_annealing(distance_matrix, demands, vehicle_capacities, time_windows, initial_temperature, cooling_rate, customer_indices)
    225 print("\nBest Solution:")
1 frames
<ipython-input-29-57e9d84fa9ef> in calculate_total_distance(route, distance_matrix, customer_indices)
    118     route_distance = 0
    119     for i in range(1, len(route)):
--> 120         route_distance += distance_matrix[customer_indices[route[i-1]]][customer_indices[route[i-1]]]
    121     return route_distance
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @user161734 please edit that information into the question, rather than leaving it as comments.